# Hide a javascript created div until all content is rendered

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a mobile webpage that needs to get some content from the web to be displayed in a modal. The modal itself is created via Javascript which is a div container which is set to `display:none` when closed.

```
<body>

  Display this content: 
    <button onclick="displayModal()">display</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var htmlContents = "<div>some pretty heavy content</div>";
     var modal = //some code to create the modal div element.
     modal.style.display = 'none';

     function displayModal() {
         modal.innerHTML = htmlContents;
         modal.style.display = 'block';
     }
  </script>

</body>
```

Then the user clicks a button, then we populate the `innerHTML` of the div with some HTML and then switch the modal to `display: block`

The problem here is that the contents we're adding to innerHTML may be pretty heavy. Lots of images and css which may take some time to render (1 or 2 seconds on old devices). However, they start poping up into the view one by one. So the user may see images and divs out of place while things render.

Is there any way to switch the modal to visible ONLY after all the contents have been rendered offscreen.

P.S: This is written on pure javascript (no jquery or any other library since performance is a concern).

Comment: Have you considered that bandwidth to download the images may be a bigger performance bottleneck than the rendering?

Comment: You can insert the html to the container, after it do a container.querySelectorAll('img') and attach onload events on all of then. when the last image has been loaded then trigger the display:block; But I think the user may want to see the content as is loads.

Comment: @Vitim.us how can i tell when all the images have been loaded?

Comment: @TimoSta Downloading the images is not a concern right now. Bandwidth may be a bottleneck, but the images need to be downloaded regardless. So i can only solve for the part i have control over: rendering.

Comment: @roloenusa You have to implement some kind of counter, that keeps track of how many images already been loaded. When the last image is loaded you know that that one is the last thing, so you unhide everything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of ways you could do this. I think if you move the  modal.innerHTML = htmlContents out of the displayModal() function you could get the images and modal contents to load before the user clicks on it. So it would look like this:

```
<body>

  Display this content: 
    <button onclick="displayModal()">display</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var htmlContents = "<div>some pretty heavy content</div>";
     var modal = //some code to create the modal div element.
     modal.style.display = 'none';
     modal.innerHTML = htmlContents;

     function displayModal() {
         modal.style.display = 'block';
     }
  </script>

</body>
```

I also found this jQuery library that may help, it seems like a lot of people are using it:
https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: the assignment of modal.innerHTML = htmlContents  inside the function block wouldn't matter much since htmlContents is just a string that takes fractions of a millisecond to assign. The jquery library seems like a good option though.

Comment: part of the requirements is to not use any outside libraries do to a few contrains. Thank you though.